# Classic ASP. Webpage has expired.! Error

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, asp-classic, iis-7

I have been scratching my head from last 2 days to find a solution for this, I tried many ways but did not work, Could some help me out with this.

I am using Classic Asp, on button click event I load a page with a grid in it and then I choose a record from the grid and it take me to a different page where it show all the details of the record. When I hit back to go back to the grid and see another records I get a error "Webpage has Expired" in IE and "Confirm form Resubmission" when I refresh the page I get a pop up with the message as below

"To Display the webpage again, the web browser needs to resend the information you've previously submitted." and so on......

With 2 buttons Retry and Cancel.

And I hit "retry" it opens the page with the grid again. So is there a way to avoid the error page and pop-up and directly open the page with the grid in it.?

I tried the "Get" Method too , Even this did not work.

I add tried the following code in mentioned in MSDN  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/183763

```
<%Response.CacheControl="Public"%>
```

And I also used the following to empty the Cache

```
Response.buffer=true
Response.Expires = -1
Response.ExpiresAbsolute = Now() -1 
Response.AddHeader "pragma", "no-store"
Response.AddHeader "cache-control","no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
```

Nothing works

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're doing something strange and/or screwy,

```
<form method="get" action="mypage.asp">
```

will not be cached, and thus will not get the "webpage expired" message.

You say "on button click event" - does this mean that you're doing everything client-side via Javascript? If so, are you *sure* the original page was requested via `method="get"`, not `post`?

Comment: It is a button in a different page like a query when I hit execute query it takes me to a different page and displays the grid.

Comment: @RookieRoll, OK, so you have Page1.asp which has a form with an 'Execute Query' button. When you press that button, Page2.asp opens in a new tab/window with the list of records. When you click a link on Page2.asp, it opens in the same tab/window, and then if you use your browser's Back button, you get the 'expired page' warning. Is this correct? If so, make sure the form on Page1.asp uses `method="get"`. If it's using Javascript to run the query, make sure the javascript isn't somehow switching the submission method on you.

Comment: No you got me half wrong here.  Page1.asp which has a form with an 'Execute Query' button. When you press that button, Page2.asp opens in a new tab/window with the list of records. When you click a link on Page2.asp, it opens in another Page3.asp. When I hit back on Page3.asp to go back to Page2.asp then I get this "WebPage Expired" Error.

Comment: @RookieRoll: that's actually what I said. Or meant to say. :) The key is that Page1.asp is the one with a form on it, and submitting said form opens a new tab/window. Clicking a link on Page2.asp does *not* open a new tab/window, which is why the back button is (or would be) useful. Bottom line is that you need to make sure Page1.asp isn't doing anything to make Page2.asp expire, and the simplest, most dependable way to do that is to make sure the form uses `method="get"`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to change the HTTP method if you specify the expiration of your page: `response.Expires=60` will keep the page buffered for the next hour.

If you change are using `<FORM method='post'>` and you change this to `<FORM method='get'>` you also have to change your receiving page to look at `request.querystring` instead of `request.form`.